# how to get the xml value of an attribute?

Tags: xml, linux, grep

I need the value of an attribute in a tag.
ex . Name xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLinst" xsi:spaceSchema="Name_5879.xsd">
        ...
     /Name>"
Can I use xml_grep toe get the value "Name_5879.xsd" ?

Answer (score 0):

```
$ xmlstarlet sel -t -m "Name" -v "@xsi:spaceSchema" input.xml 
Name_5879.xsd
```

Comment: can this be converted to a xml_grep?